# Another way to synchronizing except wait and notify?

Tags: java, multithreading

Is it there another better and newer way to synchronize threads except wait and notify. Tell me where to read about it. Thx.

Comment: "Tell me where to read about it"?? WTF? Never mind that this is not a constructive question, you could at least say _please_.

Comment: You can read about it on the Internet.

Comment: read from [java concurrency in practice](https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&ved=0CCsQFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.cs.unicam.it%2Fculmone%2F%3Fdownload%3Djava_concurrency_in_practice.pdf&ei=jCXMUdyAAci5rgf57YHYDA&usg=AFQjCNHlTD9PfmbFBll97WnuCrFFPDDLBQ&sig2=2dH8kbKH2DK8dYLxp-uJIw&bvm=bv.48340889,d.bmk)

Answer (score 1):

The packages [`java.util.concurrent`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/package-summary.html), [`java.util.concurrent.atomic`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/atomic/package-summary.html) and [`java.util.concurrent.locks`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/locks/package-summary.html) provide all kinds of high-level tools for synchronizing and working in a concurrent environment.